# Performance: should I make one or multiple queries to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a C# program that has to process about 100 000 items, and ADO.NET access to sql server database, and in one part of the program I have to make a performance decision:

Durring processing, for each item I have to read data from a database:

should I query database once for every item, or should I query once at the beginning for all items, and keep that 100 000 rows of data (about 10 columns - int and string) in c# object in memory and retrieve required data from it?

Comment: I would go with storing in memory,but again **it depends**

Comment: Is this a scenario where you could utilize a document/NoSql database?

Comment: For 100k rows, storing them all in memory at once could easily result in an `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: My personal approach would be to make fewer calls by grabbing large sections of data and storing it in memory while those records are processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a reasonably static data set, and enough memory to read everything upfront, and keep the results cached without starving of memory the rest of your system, the answer is very easy: you should do it.

There are two major components to the cost to any DB operation - the cost of the data transfer, and the cost of a round-trip. In your case, the cost of the data transfer is fixed, because the total number of bytes does not change based on whether you retrieve them all at once, or get them one chunk at a time.

The cost of a round-trip includes the time it takes RDBMS to figure out what data you need from the SQL statement, locating that data, and do all locking required to ensure that the data it serves you is consistent. A single round-trip is not expensive, but when you do it 100,000 times, the costs may very well become prohibitive. That is why it is best to read the data at once if your memory configuration allows it.

Another concern is how dynamic is your data. If the chances of your data changing in the time it takes you to process the entire set are high, you may take additional precautions to see if you need to re-process anything once your computations are done.

Comment: Having done operations like this, another concern is whether or not the data will change.  If it takes you 1ms to process a record, and you are sure your data won't change for 100 seconds, you can process all 100k records easily before any risk of change.  However, if it takes 1 second to process a record, odds may be much higher that data will change in the 27.78 hours it would take to process your data

Comment: @MarshallTigerus That's a fair observation, although I find it unlikely that the time to process 100,000 of anything would take significantly more than a few minutes.

Comment: True, but if those records are being modified within those few minutes, it matters.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I think that when reacting to an update made within a few minutes becomes essential, it becomes beneficial to rethink the strategy, e.g. by moving the logic into a stored procedure or writing a trigger. Anyway, I've done this more than once to data sets that are relatively static, to the point that I can cache the data on disk to save on the bootstrap costs for the processing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by processing but oftentimes if this processing can be done on the db server, then triggering a stored procedure and passing arguments to it would be the preferred option. You then do not need round trips etc. You have to make the decision of whether you want to *bring the data to the processing* (from db to application) or *bring the processing to the data* (processing code to stored procedure).